# Android Retrofit Interceptor add body param for all calls

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

Is there any way to edit the body of a network call for adding a default attribute used in the **95%** of the calls?

I've seen that a query parameter is pretty easy to add [(link)](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-add-query-parameters-to-every-request)

But, I have not seen it for a Body.

My problem is that I'm working with an old API that asks me to send in each request the token. So I need to add this line in most of the classes.

```
 @SerializedName("token") val token: String
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should use httpInterceptor to solve this problem if you send in header

```
final OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request()
                          .newBuilder()
                          // add token key on request header
                          // key will be using access token
                          .addHeader("token", yourToken) 
                          .build();
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
});

retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
           .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
           .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
           .client(httpClient.build())
           .build();
```

---

Edit : Im sorry, I've realized now you ask about sending in body.

I think it can be possible with old way(without Gson, Moshi etc). It is really more annoying than adding to every request.

Comment: it is not a Header so I cannot use it.  It's an old API and I'm trying to apply something in order to make it easier to work with. Thanks anyway